# OutOfMemoryError - No trace in the console

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I call the below testMethod, after putting it into a Callable(with other few Callable tasks), from an ExecutorService. I suspect that, the map.put() suffers OutOfMemoryError, as I'm trying to put some 20 million entries.

But, I'm not able to see the error trace in console. Just the thread stops still. I tried to catch the Error ( I know.. we shouldnt, but for debug I caught). But, the error is not caught. Directly enters finally and stops executing.. and the thread stands still.

```
  private HashMap<String, Integer> testMethod(
        String file   ) { 
try {
        in = new FileInputStream(new File(file));
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in), 102400);
        for (String line; (line= br.readLine()) != null;) {
            map.put(line.substring(1,17),
                    Integer.parseInt(line.substring(18,20)));
        }
        System.out.println("Loop End"); // Not executed

    } catch(Error e){
        e.printStackTrace(); //Not executed
    }finally {
        System.out.println(map.size()); //Executed
        br.close();
        in.close();
        }
return map;
}
```

Wt could be the mistake, I'm doing?

EDIT: This is how I execute the Thread.

```
Callable<Void> callable1 = new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                testMethod(inputFile);
                return null;
            }
        };

        Callable<Void> callable2 = new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                testMethod1();
                return null;
            }
        };



        List<Callable<Void>> taskList = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();
        taskList.add(callable1);
        taskList.add(callable2);


        // create a pool executor with 3 threads
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        List<Future<Void>> future = executor.invokeAll(taskList);

        //executor.invokeAll(taskList);
        latch.await();
```

`future.get(0);future.get(1); //Added this as per SubOptimal'sComment`

But, this future.get() didn't show OOME in console.

Comment: Looks like you've entered an endless loop, consuming all your resources.

Comment: Have you tried catching `Throwable` instead of Error?

Comment: Which trace do you expect? An OOME means that you are requesting a chunk of memory and there is none available. Up to that point, the program is running ok. Also, maybe there is no stacktrace because there is no memory left to generate the stacktrace...

Comment: @llogiq `OutOfMemoryError` extends `Error`; this code should work.

Comment: Try to use Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...); and second comment.

Comment: @Harbinger Maybe you should show the code how you execute the thread.

Comment: @Harbinger you need to call the `get()` method of a `Future` object, in your edited exmaple you call the `get(int)` method of a `List` object. If you change it to `future.get(0).get(); future.get(1).get();` you should see the OOME.

Answer (score 2):

You should not throw away the future after submitting the Callable.

```
Future future = pool.submit(callable);
future.get(); // this would show you the OOME
```

example based on the informations of the requestor to demonstrate

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Callable<Void> callableOOME = new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("callableOOME");
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
            // some code to force an OOME
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
                    map.put(Integer.toString(i), i);
                }
            } catch (Error e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                System.out.println("callableOOME: map size " + map.size());
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    Callable<Void> callableNormal = new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("callableNormal");
            // some code to have a short "processing time"
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    List<Callable<Void>> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    taskList.add(callableOOME);
    taskList.add(callableNormal);

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    List<Future<Void>> future = executor.invokeAll(taskList);

    System.out.println("get future 0: ");
    future.get(0).get();
    System.out.println("get future 1: ");
    future.get(1).get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try catching Throwable as it could be an Exception like IOException or NullPointerException,  Throwable captures everything except System.exit();

Another possibility is that the thread doesn't die, instead it becomes increasingly slower and slower due to almost running out of memory but never giving up.  You should be able to see this with a stack dump or using `jvisualvm` while it is running.

BTW Unless all you strings are exactly 16 characters long, you might like to call `trim()` on the to remove any padding in the String.  This could make them shorter and use less memory.

I assume you are using a recent version of Java 7 or 8.  If you are using Java 6 or older, it will use more memory as `.substring()` doesn't create a new underlying `char[]` to save CPU, but in this case wastes memory.

Comment: I'm using java 6. Actually I read numbers as String. So, trim() may replace the preceding 0's. I need them as it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, extending Throwable didnt make any difference. The thread executes the finally simply and stands still. Any other sol?

Comment: @Harbinger I suggest you step through the code in your debugger.  There is no way the finally block can be reached unless you either throw a Throwable, `return` is called or the end of the block is reached, yet you are suggesting none of these happened.  What happens if you don't close the file? btw you don't need to close `in` as closing `br` does this.

Comment: @Harbinger It has occurred to me what might be happening.  When You get an OutOfMemoryError, normal operations can also fail.  This means you can't create a new String (or stack trace) to print it out for example.  Try `map.clear();` to free some memory before you print the stack trace.